# Return value type does not match the function type despite it working in many other points in the header

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return-value

As the title reads.
I have many other functions using the included method function, just doesn't seem to like this one.

Any help is appreciated.

Also excuse my probably incorrect terminology. I'm terrible with it.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlSTC.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIPfn.png)

**Error**

```cpp
unsigned long Create_Font() noexcept
{
    using Create_Font = void(__thiscall*)(void*);
    return method<Create_Font>(66, this)(this);
}
```

**Method Function**

```cpp
template<typename out,class type>
inline out method(size_t index, type* self) noexcept
{
    return reinterpret_cast<out>((*reinterpret_cast<void***>(self))[index]);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code/errors as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.  We also can't copy the text from images, which stops us from being able to debug your code, i.e., help you.

Comment: I'm unsure as of how to do so as it's to be an injectable DLL.

Comment: Snippets are there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Create_Font` type is declared as returning `void`:

```cpp
using Create_Font = void(__thiscall*)(void*);
//                    ^-- returns void
```

But your `Create_Font` function is defined as returning `unsigned long`:

```cpp
unsigned long Create_Font() noexcept {
// ^-- returns unsigned long

    /* ... */
}
```

So your compiler will complain on `return method<Create_Font>(66, this)(this);`, because the result of `method<Create_Font>(66, this)(this)` is void, but the function needs to return an `unsigned long`.
(and there's no sensible way to "convert" void into unsigned long)